# Evaluate $\int_{1}^{2} \int_{1}^{3} \frac{xy}{x^2 +y^2} \; dx\; dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> How does one evaluate the following? $$\int_{1}^{2} \int_{1}^{3} \frac{xy}{x^2 +y^2} \, dx\, dy$$

It gets very tedious when I use a substitution method. Is there a short way to evaluate it?

Comment: what substitution you have tried??

Comment: x^2 +y^2 = t this is giving limits in y and becomes very lengthy

Comment: Is it really that bad? Via $u_1=x^2+y^2$, then $u_2=y^2$, and then $u_3=u_2+9$ and $u_4=u_2+1$... and a bitta integration by parts for $\int \ln(u_i),du_i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that : $\int \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}dx = \frac{y}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2) + C $

$$\int_{1}^{2} \int_{1}^{3} \frac{xy}{x^2 +y^2} \; dx\; dy = \int_1^2 \frac{y}{2}\ln(9+y^2)-\frac{y}{2}\ln(1+y^2)dy= \int_1^4 \frac{\ln(9+u)}{4}-\frac{\ln(1+u)}{4}du$$ where $u=y^2$ and $du=2ydy $

Setting $t=9+u$ and $dt=du$ and $s=1+u$ and $ds=du$ we have

$$\int_{10}^{13} \frac{\ln(t)}{4}dt-\int_2^5 \frac{\ln(s)}{4}ds$$

And then use integration by parts

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Observes that

$$\color{blue}{\partial_x\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) =\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}$$

Hence, $$\int_{1}^{2} \int_{1}^{3} \frac{xy}{x^2 +y^2} \; dx\; dy=\int_{1}^{2} \int_{1}^{3} \color{red}{x\partial_x\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)} \; dx\; dy$$

Then proceed by integration by part.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac12\sin2z$$ where $\sin z=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.